# Ember store selects incorrect model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm implementing new page for existing Ember application.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember           : 2.16.4
DEBUG: Ember Data      : 2.16.4
DEBUG: jQuery          : 3.3.1
DEBUG: Model Fragments : 2.14.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I added new Model `call-info.js` and there already was `call.js`

After I tried to get data with help of store

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('call-info', params.call_id);
}
```

I received object with only `id` attribute correctly set.

The problem is that store used `call.js` model for deserialization instead of `call-info.js`.

When I removed `call.js` model store returned correct object with all attributes correctly set.

Is there a way to fix this issue or somehow specify correct model ('call-info') for `this.store.findRecord` method?

Comment: Do you have a custom serializer defined in the `serializers` folder? Or are you just using the default behavior. There are different default behaviors of how response data is parsed based on the type of serializer you're using, and you might need to override that behavior. https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/

Comment: I have serializers but not for 'call' or 'call-info' models.

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5670

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was that api response contained property type

```
{
    call-info: {
     ...
     type : call,
     ...
    }
  }
```

This field forced ember store to think that model was call but not calldetail. Once I removed this field issue gone.